# Accessing a vue component's properties inside the child HTML nodes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using a [library for accordions](https://github.com/roszpun/vue-collapse) for Vue and I cannot manage to find the way to access the properties of a parent component for a child HTML node attribute.

However, I do not think this is related to the library, just my lack of experience in Vue. I guess my question would be identical with the more simple code:

```
the-parent-component
    some-other-component
        h1(v-show="//how to show/hide based on my-component.status"
```

Here is the real life example though:

- hide the delete button located in the header when the wrapper is collapsed (circled in blue)
- show it when the wrapper is open

[image: screenshot]

The library component `v-collapse-wrapper` exposes a boolean property `status` which is `true` when expanded, `false` when collapsed.

Here is the code I have to describe the accordion (pug language):

```
v-collapse-group(:only-one-active="true")
    v-collapse-wrapper.collapsed(v-for="(item, id, index) in form.items")
        div.card
            div.card-header
                h5(v-collapse-toggle="")
                    small
                        span(class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-fw collapse-indicator")
                        .
                            {{ getCardTitle(item) }}
                        a(href="#"
                          class="btn btn-sm btn-danger float-right"
                          @click.prevent="removeItem(item)")
                            | Delete
```

What I tried:

- Using `$refs`, but that does not seem to work properly (not reactive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess one way to do it would be to make a component which would wrap the whole `v-collapse-wrapper` content and have that component expose its own status property (which could then be accessed anywhere in its template).

However I feel this may not be worth it and there may be a simpler solution.